# Use TargetType as third party control in wpf

Tags: wpf, controltemplate, mahapps.metro

I am using Mahapps.Metro UI for my WPF application.
I want to modify Tile control provided by Mahapps to meet my needs. So I decided to make ControlTemplate for it. but I am unable to refer to TargetType as Tile control which is third party control. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Show code what you already tried ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) First you need to refer their assembly in your project.
2) You need to include the xaml namespace in the root(Window, ResourceDictionary or wherever you want to write template)

like ,

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
```

then use the type in your Template

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType={x:Type controls:TileControl}>
   <!--your template-->
</ControlTemplate >
```